# How to use the callback in the add_menu_page function for wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, oop

I am trying to create a custom admin menu in Wordpress with my plugin.

I've created a main file which contains:

```
/* Plugin info */
define( 'PLUGIN__DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) );

require_once( PLUGIN__DIR . 'class.properties.php' );

// Init properties
add_action( 'init', array( 'properties', 'init' ) );
```

And a class which contains:

```
<?php

class properties
{
    private static $initiated = false;

    public static function init()
    {
        if (!self::$initiated) {
            self::init_hooks();
        }
    }

    private static function init_hooks()
    {
        self::$initiated = true;
        add_menu_page('Properties', 'Properties', 'manage_options', 'cms4-properties/overzicht', 'propertiesMenu', 'dashicons-admin-multisite', 6);
    }

    public function propertiesMenu()
    {
        dd('test');
    }
}
```

I am expecting to see a dump and die message showing 'test'. But instead I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: call_user_func_array(): Argument #1 ($callback) must be a valid callback, function "propertiesMenu" not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-blocks.nl.test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php:308 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-blocks.nl.test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-blocks.nl.test\wp-includes\plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-blocks.nl.test\wp-admin\admin.php(259): do_action('toplevel_page_p...') #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp-blocks.nl.test\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 308
```

What am I doing wrong?

How come it can't find the `propertiesMenu` function?

Comment: You're missing `$this`, call the function like this way `array( $this, 'propertiesMenu' )`

Comment: @VijayHardaha Thanks but this is a static function, I cannot use $this in it

Comment: then define `propertiesMenu()` as static as well and use `__CLASS__` instead of `$this`.